# Which is correct English? "The girl who(m) they say is a singer"

Tags: british-english, whom, who

> The girl who they say is a singer, met me last night.

or

> The girl whom they say is a singer, met me last night.

Note: We Follow British English.

Comment: Forget the pesky embedded clause: The girl who they say is a singer. Or you can omit the _who_ and spare yourself the question.

Comment: In this particular example, it would not be incorrect to use *whom*, as "the girl" is the object of the clause. But as @KarlG points out - it is simpler to leave it out altogether. "Girl" does not need a capital G unless it begins the sentence.

Comment: @WS2: The embedded clause has no effect on the case of the relative. "They say she's a singer. a girl who is a singer. Some clever soul has invented the rubbish term "nominative whom" to cover such cases, but really, one should just discard "whom" entirely.

Comment: I think that both _who_ and _whom_ are valid and that both may be omitted.

Comment: Either way, you can't use just one comma.  It is possible to have parenthetical commas with one before *they* (in which case it is 'who') or none at all (in which case it is `whom').

Answer (score 1):

You could use either as correct English.

By the way, *who(m) they say is a singer* is a relative clause. This means it needs parenthesis surrounding it. You have also added a capital *"G"* for girl. Since it is not a proper (but common) noun, it does not need one.

With the correct punctuation and grammar, it should read like this:

The **g**irl**,** **who** they say is a singer**,** met me last night.

**---------------------------------------------------OR------------------------------------------------------------**

The **g**irl**,** **whom** they say is a singer**,** met me last night

Comment: The thing is, it is a clause that begins with a relative pronoun (the five relative pronouns are who, whom, whose, which and that). This makes it a relative clause.

Comment: The commas depend on how it's meant to be read. In this case, I'd argue you shouldn't use commas. "The girl who they say is a singer", as opposed to some other girl. But if the context is unambiguous and there's only one girl in question, then "The girl, who they say is a singer, ..."

Comment: Whatever _whom_ is, it's not the object of _say_, but the subject of _is_. Just because a lot of people are thrown off by an embedded clause like _they say_ doesn't mean it makes sense to leave _is_ with an oblique subject.

Comment: @AleksandrH, this would mean it is not an embedded clause and; therefore, you wouldn't need a comma after sing. I assumed that Anus Gupta's original sentence was to contain this information as a separate clause and just (likely accidentally) missed out one of the commas.

Comment: @KarlG I was not talking about the usage of the pronoun, just the identification of the clause.

Comment: @WilliamPennanti: except you are presenting _whom they say_ as the correct parsing, which it isn't.

Comment: @AleksandrH If you put a comma after "singer", but none after "who(m)", it is not parenthetical. That means you have punctuation standing between the subject and predicate of the main sentence - which is surely and absolute no-no.

Comment: @WS2 I'm suggesting that there be no commas at all in the sentence: "The girl who they say is a singer met me last night."

Comment: That would be perfectly fine.